# What use instead of TaskInternal execute() at gradle-5.1.1?

Tags: gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, google-fabric

My custom task at `gradle-4.10.1`:

```
task fabricUploadApkDevelop(group: "fabric", dependsOn: ['assembleDevDebug']) {
    doLast {
        //fabric gradle task `assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDevelop` and options:
        def task = tasks.getByName("crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug")
        task.ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "develop"
        task.ext.betaDistributionNotifications = true
        task.ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = "${project.rootDir}/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/releaseNotes.txt"
        task.execute()
    }
}
```

But at `gradle-5.1.1`:

`TaskInternal.execute()` is removed, so now I can't run my `task.execute()`, how to change my custom task? Or how to run task `crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug` with params via terminal?

I tried to use:

```
  //gradle 5.x
task fabricUploadApkDevelop(group: "fabric") {
    ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "develop"
    ext.betaDistributionNotifications = true
    ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = "${project.rootDir}/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/releaseNotes.txt"

    doLast {
        ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "develop"
        ext.betaDistributionNotifications = true
        ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = "${project.rootDir}/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/releaseNotes.txt"
    }

    finalizedBy 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug'
}
```

But `crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug` task doesn't get params...

Comment: just declare task with params you need and do dependency on it. no exec needed... `task A(type: XYZ) {
     parm1 = "..."
     parm2 = "..."
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sources for the Fabric/Crashlytics Gradle plugin don’t seem to be publicly available (and I have never used it myself), otherwise I would have checked there. But given your working example for Gradle 4 and looking at the issue through my vanilla Gradle glasses, I’d expect that the following should/could work with Gradle 5:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug.doFirst {
        ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "develop"
        ext.betaDistributionNotifications = true
        ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = "${project.rootDir}/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/releaseNotes.txt"
    }
}

task fabricUploadApkDevelop(group: "fabric") {
    dependsOn 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug'
}
```

I’d even expect there to be a nicer way to do it but since I can’t test this myself, I wanted to play it safe. Let me know if it worked or what didn’t!

Comment: `Could not get unknown property 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! It seems that the `crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug` task is defined later than the `fabricUploadApkDevelop` task. I have updated the code to be more conservative. Should that still not work, then I’d wonder if you have changed anything else in your configuration apart from the Gradle version?