# Gradle: replacing task.execute() in migrating to Gradle 5 from 4

Tags: gradle, task

Gradle: how to replace task.execute() in migrating to Gradle 5.4.1 from 4.x.
For example,

```
Task foo() {
    doLast {
       bar.execute();
    }
}

Task bar() {
    ...
}
```

Gradle 5 does not support calling task.execute().

```
mustRunAfter/shouldRunAfter
```

can not replace it since the task bar may not run.

```
foo.finalizedBy bar
```

does not run bar after foo. Could not find detail docs for finalizedBy method.

Comment: *`foo.finalizedBy bar` does not run bar after foo* Well, but it should. Could you post the detailed output of calling `gradle foo`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What use instead of TaskInternal execute() at gradle-5.1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56163312/what-use-instead-of-taskinternal-execute-at-gradle-5-1-1)

Comment: `finalizedBy` ensures `bar` is run after `foo`. Though it does not guarantee to run immediately after `foo`. so there could be other tasks be executed in between